# Android Handler stops increasing number

Tags: android

I have a handler set to increase a number by a certain amount every 0.2 seconds. It works fine up until it hits the number 33,554,432 (2^26) now the number that it stops at does change depending on how slow I set the handler to run, but I need it set at 0.2 seconds.

Another problem that I am having is that upon changing activities, and then going back to the main activity, the speed of the handler doubles and goes back to normal speed when the app has been closed, I have recorded this happening using Log.d(), the number however, increases at the same speed as before.

This is the code I have used for the handler:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView number;

    private Button increase100, increase1000, increase10000, increase100000, increase1000000;

    float current_number = 0;
    float numberIncreaseBy = 10;

    DecimalFormat intFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            numberIncrease();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        number = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TXT_number);

        increase100 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_increase100);
        increase1000 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_increase1000);
        increase10000 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_increase10000);
        increase100000 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_increase100000);
        increase1000000 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN_increase1000000);

        numberIncrease();
        increaseBy100();
        increaseBy1000();
        increaseBy10000();
        increaseBy100000();
        increaseBy1000000();
    }

    public void numberIncrease()
    {
        Log.d("Handler", "Triggered");
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 200);

        //Divide by 5 so it increases by 2 every 0.2 seconds for a total of 10 per second
        current_number = (current_number + (numberIncreaseBy / 5));

        String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
        number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
    }

    public void increaseBy100()
    {
        increase100.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                current_number = current_number + 100;

                String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
                number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
            }
        });
    }

    public void increaseBy1000()
    {
        increase1000.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                current_number = current_number + 1000;

                String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
                number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
            }
        });
    }

    public void increaseBy10000()
    {
        increase10000.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                current_number = current_number + 10000;

                String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
                number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
            }
        });
    }

    public void increaseBy100000()
    {
        increase100000.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                current_number = current_number + 100000;

                String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
                number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
            }
        });
    }

    public void increaseBy1000000()
    {
        increase1000000.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                current_number = current_number + 1000000;

                String formattedNumber = intFormatter.format(current_number);
                number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is my activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.goldsters.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TXT_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BTN_increase100000"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_increase100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increase 100"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_increase1000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increase 1000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BTN_increase100"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_increase10000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increase 10000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BTN_increase1000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_increase100000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increase 100000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BTN_increase10000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BTN_increase1000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Increase 1000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BTN_increase100000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the number to continue increasing up until Float.MAX_VALUE

Comment: You should be using the `CountDownTimer` class.

Comment: I changed the Handler to a CountDownTimer but it still continues to stop at 33,554,432.

Comment: This is not the problem, but in any case `number.setText(String.valueOf(formattedNumber));` should be `number.setText(formattedNumber);` as it is already s String

Comment: Thank you, I changed that in my code.